# Is Roslyn a full compiler?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, roslyn

Is Roslyn a full standalone C# compiler? I looked a bit around the source code and it seems like it uses the compiler from Visual Studio, also, I didn't find any source code in it's GitHub repository (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) which have something to do with parsing.

Comment: Yes. And the parser is [there](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser).

Comment: The first line in your linked page says "The .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") provides open-source C# and Visual Basic compilers", so yes it is a full compiler...

Comment: Where did you see it uses the VS compiler? (just a note: there isn't a VS compiler)

Comment: I really don't get why this is down-voted, it's a perfectly legitimate question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Roslyn is a full C# (and VB!) compiler.

As a starting point, here's the source code for `csc.exe`, the actual compiler binary: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/csc/Csc.cs

The actual parser is at: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser